# “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy” and “Strip Linked Product” difference on xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, crash-reports, symbolicate

1. What is a difference between “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy” and “Strip Linked Product” options?
2. What does it mean if “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy” = YES and “Strip Linked Product” = NO?
3. Is it possible to upload an application to the App Store with symbolicated data on the separate .dsym file (not on the binary)?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

On the latest version of xCode on the new project the default options works well. So, it's not required to change them any more.

Comment: You answered your own question but it's not an answer to the original quesition. It does not tell the difference between “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy” and “Strip Linked Product” options.

Comment: Just use default values and forget about them. There are so many things in the World that you shouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

from apple documentation:

**Strip Debug Symbols During Copy**

Description: Boolean value. Specifies whether copied binaries are stripped of debugging symbols.

```
Values:
YES: Copied binaries are stripped of debugging symbols. This does not cause the binary produced by the linker to be stripped. Use "Strip Linked Product" to have the linker strip the binary.
NO: Copied binaries are not stripped of debugging symbols
Default value: NO
```

**Strip Linked Product**

Description: Boolean value. Specifies whether to strip symbol information from the binary.

```
Values:
YES: Strips the generated binary when the prerequisite is met.
NO: Does not strip the generated binary.
Default value: NO
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html